# KeyError 0 when trying to traverse session dictionary in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, keyerror

I'm trying to traverse the session variable to print out all of its contents.

```
for s in request.session:
    print str(s)
```

The resulting error is as follows

```
KeyError at /<app name>/searchResults/
0
```

With the following traceback.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
    115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

/<path to django app>/views.py
    106. for s in request.session:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __getitem__
    46 return self.__session[key]
```

Any idea what '0' means as an error?  I've never seen this kind of thing before.

Comment: what does `print request.session` before the loop give you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to iterate over the session's values is `request.session.itervalues()` - the base session class exposes the same key/value/item options as a standard dictionary.  I am unsure so far where it's getting the values your for loop is finding, but it's not the values.

Comment: itervalues seems to just give me the values, is there a way to get the keys?

Comment: It's the same methods as a standard dictionary - `iterkeys` would give you the keys, or `iteritems` key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You class is missing the __iter__ member... thats all.

You can probably subclass it to fix the bug.

e.g.

```
class IterableRequest(Request):
  def __iter__(self): return self.iterkeys()
```

*Maybe this next hack might fix the problem:*

```
Request.__iter__=Request.iterkeys
```

See also:

- [What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/understanding-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols-what-exact)

I'd be tempted to check the source and confirm it is a bug, and then make a bug report.